# What kind of Java collection should I use for this?

Tags: java, collections

I am fairly new to Java and am having trouble understanding the differences between different collections. I have a list of 19 resources. Each resource is assigned a hex color. I want to get a random resource with its color and use that resource with my code. Once I am finished with the current resource, I want to remove it from the list so that only a certain number of resources are used.

Should I use a dictionary, map, or hashtable? Or any others that I am missing.

Comment: `List<Resource>` might work for your specific use case.  Do you imagine you will ever need to lookup a resource based on something like the hex color?

Comment: I don’t understand your exact requirements, but if something like a dictionary or map, then `HashMap` would be the standard choice.

Comment: Need more information. Do you need them sorted in any way? Can a resource be added more than once? Does the resource got an identifier of some sort which is available to you and you search by it for a specific resource, or do you just go over all the resources at once and use them?

Comment: I would either need to shuffle the elements or be able to get a random element one at a time.  I don't think I would have the need to get a resource by it's color.

Comment: So it sounds like a map is ruled out. Can a resource be added more than once?

Comment: In my opinon, even ArrayList works fine if you are looking for fast access. For quick adding and removal, you can consider LinkedList.

Comment: since you have only 19 items, use whatever you want. you'll never notice a change

Comment: `ArrayList` is fine. `Collections.shuffle()` will make sure you get your ressorces out in random order.

Comment: ArrayList wouldn't work because I need to assign the color(value) to the resource(key)

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Do you need 1 to 1 mapping for color and resource? More importantly, must the color value be unique in your collection?

Comment: well, i'm starting to wonder what are the **19 resources** actually are.. as one answer pointed out, it may a class that contains the color.. but, you did mention a map - key-value relationship..

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 you wrote at first " I don't think I would have the need to get a resource by it's color" and then you write "I need to assign the color(value) to the resource(key)"... So what is it?

Answer (score 11):

What you could do, is store your resources into a `List`, then randomly permutes it thanks to [`Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) or [`shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-java.util.Random-), and finally call [`iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator--) on the resulting list to get an instance of `Iterator` that you could store into a member field to be able to iterate over your list (thanks to [`hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext--)/[`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--)) and remove your resource once done with [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--).

Here is a pseudo code using `String` as resource just to show the idea:

```
// Create a read/write list (Arrays.asList returns a read-only list)
List<String> resources = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
System.out.printf("Initial state = %s%n", resources);
Collections.shuffle(resources);
System.out.printf("Permuted List = %s%n", resources);
Iterator<String> iterator = resources.iterator();
if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String resource = iterator.next();
    // do something
    iterator.remove();
    System.out.printf("After remove = %s%n", resources);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Initial state = [1, 2, 3]
Permuted List = [3, 1, 2]
After remove = [1, 2]
```

**NB:** This approach makes sense in your case as you have a small list, please note that if you have a big list and you intend to retrieve only a small part of it, you should consider using a [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) to get randomly the index of the next element (using [`nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) with `list.size()` as parameter) to get (using [`get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-)) and remove (using [`remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-)) instead of using `Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)` as it would cause an overhead.

---

> `ArrayList` wouldn't work because I need to assign the color(value) to
>   the resource(key)

Yes it can work if you use a `List` of a wrapper class that will contain both, your color and your resource (for example [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html) or simply a custom class). It is good enough as you don't seem to need to retrieve the color by resource. If you do, you could simply have a `Map` with resource as key and color as value and use `new ArrayList<>(map.keySet())` to initialize your list of resources, then you will be able to apply what is proposed previously in this answer.

Comment: Note that if only a small fraction of elements from the initial list is picked randomly, shuffling the whole list causes overhead for large lists.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I agree but here the list is composed of only `19` elements so I don't believe that the overhead would be so big in this case especially if it is done only once, the overhead would then be insignificant.

Comment: Note that the `new ArrayList` is necessary since the one returned from `Arrays.asList` would throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` when you try to remove an element.

Comment: @JollyJoker yes that's right, `Arrays.asList` returns a read only list

Comment: @NicolasFilotto You are right, That's why I also upvoted your answer. But since this question already received some upvotes a larger audience may reuse your ideas and I think its good if they are aware of the possible overhead.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Meant more as an FYI for others reading your answer, obviously you knew.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to lookup (get) resource based on its hex use following

```
// Initialize
Map<String, Resource> resourceMap = new HashMap<>();
resourceMap.put("hex1", hex1Resource);
resourceMap.put("hex2", hex3Resource);
resourceMap.put("hex3", hex3Resource);

// Get specific
Resource hex2Resource = resourceMap.get("hex2");
resourceMap.remove("hex2");
```

If you want to lookup resource randomly, there are 2 options

- Use List (this allows duplicates)
- Use Set (stores only unique values)

**Using Lists**

```
// Initialize
List<Resource> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(resource1);
list.add(resource2);
list.add(resource3);

// Get random
Random rand = new Random();
Resource randomResource = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));

// Delete the element from list
list.remove(randomResource);
```

**Using Sets**

```
// Initialize
Set<Resource> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(resource1);
set.add(resource2);
set.add(resource3);

// Convert to List, since Set does not have get(int) method. 
List<Resource> list = new ArrayList<>(set);

// Get random
Random rand = new Random();
Resource randomResource = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));

// Delete the element from list
list.remove(randomResource);
```

***Note***: For both cases above, Resource class will need to implement methods equals and hashcode so that list/set can compare elements and work correctly. See [Java equals and hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java?rq=1)

**Update**: Sets do not have get(int) method. Updated the code to fix this.

Comment: Just a small question, how would lists and sets solve the purpose here? He needs a resource and a color associated with it, you're storing only either of them in the list or set.

Comment: @sameerasy There's always the option of `List<Map.Entry<Color,Resource>>`, or a custom wrapper class for the data.

Comment: He should mention that, right? @4castle If you look at his list declaration it's just `List<Resource>`

Comment: @4castle, what if the Color is not key? it might be duplicate according to the question.

Comment: @gtiwari333 A `List` will allow duplicates.

Comment: @4castle, I'm talking about Map.Entry<Color,Resource>

Comment: @gtiwari333 I'm confused. What mechanism would remove duplicate entries? You can create entries by just doing `new SimpleEntry<>(color, resource)`

Comment: Here Resource class is assumed to have property of color (string), and equals and hashcode are based on the same.

Comment: @4castle, you are right. I initially thought List<Map.Entry> as List<Map> :)

Comment: `java.util.Set` has no `get` method. Therefore the *Using Sets* example won't compile.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker You are correct. I completely missed it. Have updated the code. Thanks much!

Comment: @DeepakV You also have to use `list` now instead of `set` in `set.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));`

Comment: @SpaceTrucker damn, this is embarrassing. Updated. Thanks much sir!

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. The steps are:

1. Create a list of Resource
2. Generate a random number and get the item
3. Do what you want to do with your random item
4. Remove it from list

### Example Code:

```
 //1
List<Resource> resources= getList();

//2
Random generator = new Random();
Resource randomResource = resources.get(generator.nextInt(resources.size() -1));

//3
//do your stuff

//4
resources.remove(randomResource);
```

Resource can be a class which wraps your data

```
class Resource{
    String color;
    String otherProperties;
    //..


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //generate from IDE or write one
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //generate from IDE or write one
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

if u need random order better you can go for List object.

```
List<String> resourceMap = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
          resourceMap.add("hex1");
          resourceMap.add("hex2");
          resourceMap.add("hex3");
          resourceMap.add("hex4");
          Collections.shuffle(resourceMap);
          resourceMap.forEach(resource->{
              resourceMap.remove(resource);
          });
```